# What is the origin of feminine ending *-ia in PIE?

Tags: gender, proto-indo-european

I have seen two versions:

a) **-ia* ending actually derived from the collective number form, which also ends in **-ia*. So the collective number first started to represent abstract things (compare Latin *animalia*, Greek *zooia*), and then came to mark feminine gender.

b) From Eurasiatic **haia*, "mother", from Borean **haia*, "mother" (see [Nostratic etymology](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Cnostr%5Cnostret&first=1&off=&text_proto=%CA%94VjV&method_proto=substring&ic_proto=on&text_meaning=mother&method_meaning=substring&ic_meaning=on&text_ier=&method_ier=substring&ic_ier=on&text_alt=&method_alt=substring&ic_alt=on&text_ura=&method_ura=substring&ic_ura=on&text_kart=&method_kart=substring&ic_kart=on&text_drav=&method_drav=substring&ic_drav=on&text_esk=&method_esk=substring&ic_esk=on&text_chuk=&method_chuk=substring&ic_chuk=on&text_notes=&method_notes=substring&ic_notes=on&text_reference=&method_reference=substring&ic_reference=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=proto&ic_any=on)) which explains similar feminine **-ia* endings in Semitic, IE and Altaic.

The account for Laryngeal theory is only compatible with version a) and cannot explain how Eurasiatic **-ia* became PIE **-ih<sub>2</sub>.*

Comment: most linguists do not accept the validity of genetic groupings higher than IE, but you might find someone familiar with the super-lumping hypotheses who will answer.

Comment: Good question! Just a side note: as far as I can tell, *tetrapoda* comes from Greek, not Latin.

Comment: if the late PIE m/f/n gender system arose from an earlier two-way animacy system as is often conjectured, it seems like that presents an additional difficulty for option (b). But in support of (a), I have seen this theory of the collective ending leading to the feminine before, e.g. at the [sci.lang FAQ #28](http://www.zompist.com/lang21.html#28)

Comment: Looking at the link you posted, all I can see is Eurasiastic *ʔVjV ? and Borean *HVJV. Doesn't V there stand for an unspecified vowel?

Comment: The last sentence looks like it's describing a difficulty for laryngeal theory, but if anything, it's describing a difficulty for the Euroasiatic theory.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to really know for sure how a feminine marker "originated" in Indo-European, since the exact nature of gender there is unknown, since Hittite conveys only two genders (or states): animate and inanimate. Furthermore, "animalia" is a neuter plural. Nevertheless, it suffices to say that the Semitic ending in Arabic ة-/ية (-ah/iyah) is not at all related to the Indo-European one. Take for example a Berber word for "house": "tamdint"; the t-t indicates a feminine. The root is "mdn" like "مدينة" (medīnah, city) in Arabic, which becomes "مدينات" (medīnāt, cities) in the plural. Therefore the Eurasiatic theory is far-fetched. 
I might not have fully answered your question, but at least this hopefully narrows it. I think it is important to ponder this sort of thing, but the answer will likely never be known.